# Inconsistent font rendering when using a remote kernel on a different OS

Tags: parallelization, fonts, compatibility, rendering

I have a *Mathematica* 10.0 on Linux and one on OSX. I'm using the OSX as a remote kernel.

During parallel computation, if I render some graphics, the fonts and axes are not rendered the same way depending on which platform the calculation was carried out on (Linux or OSX). To be more clear, here is illustrative code:

```
ParallelDo[Module[{temp},
  temp = DensityPlot[t, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 15}];
  Export[ToString[t] <> ".png", temp]], {t, 1, 2}]
```

The two image exported are the following:

[image: Computed on Linux kernel][image: Computed on OSX kernel]

There is a slight difference in rendering. What can I do to have exactly the same rendering independent of the platform?

Note that in the above example code, using a `ParallelTable` function would solve the problem since the rendering is done on the Linux platform when asked. But for my purpose I have to use a `ParrallelDo` and `Export` at each iteration.

Comment: Any more luck with exporting vector formats (EPS,  PDF etc.)? I guess pixel-perfect reproduction on different platform will be...  difficult.